# "Because of its negative impacts" or "impact"

Tags: word-usage

Could I ask is the sentence in the title right?

> Because of its negative ***impacts***, stealing has been considered by many people a problem.

Should I use "***Because of its impacts***" or "***Because of its impact***", assuming it has many negative impacts that I have mentioned before.
Thank you very much!

Or maybe I should use "effects"?

Comment: You might consider giving a full sentence as a context. Who/what has an impact on whom/what?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I mean, I listed a range of negative impacts of stealing (on property, reputation, etc.) before this sentence. Then I write this sentence, is this sentence right in such context?

Answer (score 3):

Even if ***impact*** is in the singular, it can have a *collective* connotation to cover ALL negative effects of stealing.

In dictionaries like [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/impact) or [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impact), you will find that the singular of ***impact*** is exclusively used in the examples they provide.

[Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impact%2C%20impacts&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimpact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpacts%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows that the singular of "impact" is preferred.

But it is [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/impact.html) that provides a satisfactory explanation to your question:

```
The noun "impact" can be countable or uncountable. In more general,
commonly used, contexts, the plural form will also be "impact". However,
in more specific contexts, the plural form can also be "impacts" e.g. in
reference to various types of impacts or a collection of impacts.
```

So, if your intention is to refer to ***various types of impacts***, then you can use the plural. If the differences between the negative effects of stealing is not so important you can treat them as a whole, and use the singular of "impact".

Comment: Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

*Impact* or *impacts* both work fine, the plural just implies a wider range of possible issues, rather than the overall impact as a whole. *Impact* sounds like you have something specific in mind, as though you're talking about a particular set of consequences, whereas *impacts* could seem more vague.

Personally I'd either phrase it as *stealing has been **considered a problem by many people***, or *stealing has been **considered by many people to be a problem***. The phrase *by many people a problem* doesn't flow very well.

*Considered **to be** a problem* can be shortened to *considered a problem*, but taking that and breaking it apart with another phrase sounds clumsy. If you do want to insert *by many people* after *considered*, it reads better if you keep the whole clause intact: *considered by many to be...*

Comment: Thank you very much!